How to correlate emails between Microsoft Graph API and Office 365 Management Activity API?
I'm developing an email analytics application that needs to track who sends emails from shared mailboxes. To do this, I'm using two Microsoft APIs:

Microsoft Graph API: to get the email data
Office 365 Management Activity API: to get audit logs that show who actually is sending emails from a Shared Mailbox.

The problem
When trying to correlate the same email between these two APIs, I've noticed that the `internet_message_id` field sometimes differs between them, even though other properties (timestamp, subject) confirm it's the same email.
This inconsistency happens intermittently — sometimes the IDs match perfectly, other times they don't.
Environment

Microsoft Graph API v1.0
Office 365 Management Activity API v1.0
Rest API calls (no SDK)
Application permissions for both APIs

The tenant where we’re experiencing this issue has the following setup:

Active Directory on-premises synced to Azure AD
Exchange Server Hybrid with all users and Shared Mailboxes in Exchange Online
Exchange attributes synced to Azure AD/Exchange Online
Users accessing email through a mix of Outlook.com and Outlook Desktop clients

My questions

Is this expected when correlating data between these APIs?
Could this variation be related to the user using different email clients (Outlook Desktop vs Outlook.com)?
Is there a more reliable way to correlate emails between these two sources?

Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Has anyone else encountered this issue when working with these APIs?

You might want to try using the NetworkId instead from any of the following if available see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/monitoring/trace-an-email-message/message-trace-modern-eac

X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id

eg
$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(id eq 'String {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} name x-ms-exchange-crosstenant-network-message-id') or (id eq 'String {00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} name X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id'))

The NetworkId can be used in a MessageTrace


 Get-MessageTraceDetail -MessageTraceId 808bbf42-fdf5-4ff4-c83f-08dd0fefdf82 -RecipientAddress user@domain



InternetMessageId can be problematic for a few reason as any MTA can add/modify this value in Transit. They should be globally unique but in practice its not guaranteed hence why Microsoft generate their own network message ID's.
Also Messages stored in the SendItems folders are a copy of the Message being sent (done at the MessageStore level) before it has been processed by any MTA's so the values you find on those messages may be different from what you see received.

I have not been able to obtain any data (through graph API) related to the Network-Message-Id or the Correlation-Id of the sent messages. I have seen some of these properties in the headers of the received messages, but I have not been able to get them directly using the 'expand' query.

Sent messages are the exception because they are copies of the message being sent (done by the Message Store Submission Service) not the actual message so that's why you can have a different InternetMessageId's and the other properties because they are added InTransit and won't be available on the copy stored in Sent Items.
